# Gatsby - doesn't render data if SEO component is nested in another component

Tags: module, gatsby

I'm new in Gatsby, so can anyone explain to me, why Gatsby doesn't render metadata if SEO component is nested in another component. For example:

```
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"



const IndexPage = () => {
  const [modal, showModal] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <Layout modal={modal} showModal={showModal} >
        <SEO title="PKM"/>
      </Layout>
      
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage;
```

The above will render empty places in meta, title, author. The below works perfectly well:

```
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"



const IndexPage = () => {
  const [modal, showModal] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <Layout modal={modal} showModal={showModal} />
      <SEO title="PKM"/>
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: There's no reason that shouldn't work but it of course depends on what's inside SEO and Layout. Are you using a specific starter? Have you modified the code?

Comment: I used gatsby-new starter. SEO is like it was created with it. I modified Layout like below: 
~~~
const Layout = props => {
  const [menu, showMenu] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Menu
        menu={menu}
        showMenu={showMenu}
        contentData={data}
        setData={setData}
      />
      <ModalWindow
        modal={props.modal}
        showModal={props.showModal}
        contentData={data}
      />
      <Content />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
~~~